# Getting HTTP Status 415 on remote server

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

i have hosted an application on open shift and now i am experiencing an odd situation. I have one method given below.

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/saveDetails", method = POST)
@ResponseBody
public User saveUserDetails(@RequestBody User user){
    return userService.addUser(user);
}
```

Now when i post user object using fire fox plugin 'httpPoster',

> it works fine on localhost

, [image]

> but on open shift server, it returns 415 code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be **method = RequesMethod.POST**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveDetails", method = RequestMethod.POST).
```

Btw a small suggestion, try not using the  verbs to describe the rest services.